# How to set "Restart options" on Windows Server 2019 when it blocks me saying, "Some settings are managed by your organization"?

Tags: reboot, windows-server-2019

A Windows Update requires a reboot on my Windows Server 2019 Azure VM, so I want to schedule my restart for a particular time (5am) when people won't be working via RDP on this busy application server. However, if I click Start, type in "restart", then click "Schedule your restart" from the Start menu's search results, I get the "Restart options" screen but I'm stumped by the warning in red text, “*Some settings are managed by your organization”. I'm unable to "Pick a time" because the settings are disabled, and what it's set to is unacceptable. I created this domain on the cloud, and am the administrator. I do not recall ever blocking access to this. How can I get around this obstacle?

[image]

Comment: The only reason this option would be disabled, is if you had a related policy disabled, it doesn't neccessary have to be the policy that specifically allow or disallows this behavior.  The blue text will link you to which polciies have been set, you should provide us a list of policies, that you specifically configured  on your domain.

Answer (score 0):

By default, "Schedule a time" is greyed out and requires a pending restart to turn
it on. 
This is not the general option you are looking for.

You should look instead into enabling automatic active hours.

In Windows 10, and perhaps on Windows Server 2019, use these steps:

- Open *Settings > Update & Security > Windows Update*
- Toggle of "Automatically adjust active hours for this device based on activity"
- Click *Change*
- Set your hours and click *Save*

You will find more options in the Local Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`) at:
*Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Update*.

Another interesting place to look into is inside the registry at
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU`.

But note that the effect of any of the above may be changed by Microsoft with
each update, so vigilance is required.

Comment: I don't want to let the system adjust the reboot time based on activity. I want restarts to happen strictly at 5am. Also, I did set the active hours already from 6am -12am (not the most desirable, but it will only let me set 18 hour spaces of time).

Comment: My answer says to disable adjusting the reboot time based on activity. If the interface does not let you do what you want, do it via the registry. If you tell me exactly what you intend, I may be able to help.

Comment: I want to schedule my restart for a particular time (5am) when people won't be working via RDP on this busy application server.

Comment: You could perhaps change the active hours to include up to 4 AM.